# How to group windows during switching?

Tags: windows-7, gui, user-interface

I like how different windows of the same program are grouped on a taskbar in Windows 7. It's very handy when you need to have many windows opened in the same time. But in a pane which appears during window switching with Alt+Tab windows stay in a mess. Is there a way to group windows in the pane like it's made in a GNOME shell in Linux for example?

Comment: If you mean ‘Workspace” then you could try some equivalent for Windows 7 searching the web for ‘virtual desktop’. MS has one called Desktops but there are a few more from third-party as well. I use the MS one, but be aware that it is not as functional as the GNU variant.

Comment: @arch-abit No. I'm looking for something like [this](https://wiki.gnome.org/Projects/GnomeShell/CheatSheet?action=AttachFile&do=get&target=shortcuts-Alt-Tab.png). There are two Firefox windows grouped in one block which is shown only when its icon is in focus during window switching.